# How do I find the order of this quotient group?

Tags: group-theory

If $G=\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and $H=35 \mathbb{Z} \times 97 \mathbb{Z}$, what is $|G/H|$?

It has been some time since I've studied groups. My thoughts are that perhaps $\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and $H \cong (35 \times 97 )\mathbb{Z}=3395 \mathbb{Z}$ so that $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}_{3395}$ and the answer is $3395$?

Comment: $Z\cong Z\times Z$ is not correct, the latter is not cyclic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, $\Bbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}^2$. Now, you can actually identify $G/H$ by looking at the homomorphism $$\Bbb{Z}^2 \to \Bbb{Z}/35 \times \Bbb{Z}/97:(a,b)\mapsto ([a]_{35},[b]_{97}).$$ If you show that this homomorphism is surjective and that its kernel is $H$, you will have $G/H\cong \Bbb{Z}/35 \times \Bbb{Z}/97$ (by the first isomorphism theorem) which is of order $35\cdot 97$.

Comment: Thank you. I can easily fill in the details now.